# Shiny selectInput named choices the result of the variable

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I couldn't find a solution anywhere,

I have this selector with named variables:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
uiOutput('input')
)
#server.r

server = function(input, output) {

    output$input <- renderUI({

        variable1 <- 'dog'
        variable2 <- 'cat'
        variable3 <- 'mouse'


        selectInput(inputId = 'something',
                    label = 'select animal',
                    choices = c(variable1 = 'animal1',
                                variable2= 'animal2',
                                variable3 = 'animal3'))

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to see the result of each variable rather than the name of the variable. I mean I want to be able to select between `dog`, `cat`, or `mouse`. But it has to remain a named choice since in later I will have to use those values as `animal1`, `animal2` or `animal3`.

That's why this is ***NOT*** a solution for me, since it's not named. Even though it produces the selector that I want.

```
        selectInput(inputId = 'something',
                    label = 'select animal',
                    choices = c(variable1,
                                variable2,
                                variable3 ))
```

[image]

I have tried several attempts like `as.character()` or making it inside a vector/list but couldn't make this work.

Comment: From the heklp for `selectInput`: "choices List of values to select from. If elements of the list are named, then that name — rather than the value — is displayed to the user."  So wouldn't `choices=c("dog"="animal1", "cat"="animal2", "mouse"="animal3")` give you what you want? Also, if using the tidyverse, be aware of the concepts of both [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)ness and [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Limey , yes of course. That is correct. However, this is just a reproducible example, in my real application, the words: `dog`, `cat` and `mouse` will change and depend on the user. That's why I have to use `variable1`, `variable2` and `variable3`.

Comment: Btw, @Limey why did you say about being aware of being tidyness? Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: If the selections change according to the user, then you're probably going to need `updateSelectInput` in your server function rather than defining the options with variables in the UI function.  My reference to tidyness was because the names of your variables (`variableX`) made me think that you might be `select`ing variables from a wide dataset when `filter`ing observations from a long dataset *might* be easier.  But you've not given us a use case with test data, so I can't be sure. FWIW, I would always go for the long option if both were feasible: it's more robust.

Comment: Thanks, @Limey, I will look into `updateSelecInput`. I already found a workaround, but it's not so clean. And thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, thanks to your question and the advice of looking at `updateSelectInput`, I have solved it.

If you still need, here is the answer...

1. In `global.R`, create a list with the names of your variables.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


list_of_variables <- list('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')  

#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('input')
)
```

2. In `selectInput, choices` write `"variable1", "variable2" and "variable3"` as strings.
   Indeed, `choices` needs the names that will be shown in the selector ONLY in char/string format, i.e. `choices = c("string" = variable/number/string/list-whatever)` (see https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.2/selectInput.html).
   This is the reason why you can't use a variable here.

```
#server.r

server = function(input, output, session) {  # Add "session" in function(input, output, session)
  
  output$input <- renderUI({
    
    selectInput(inputId = 'something',
                label = 'select animal',
                choices = list('variable1' = 'animal1',   
                               'variable2' = 'animal2',   
                               'variable3' = 'animal3'))
  })
```

3. To have a variable in the selector list, you need to change the names entered in char/string format, "updating" them in a second step with `updateSelectInput`.
   In `server.R` you can add the code below, which recalls your `inputId = 'something'` and sobstitutes the old `choices` string names with your `(list_of_variables)`

```
  observe({           
    updateSelectInput(           
      session,
      'something',
      choices = unique(list_of_variables)
    )
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here you can find more info about `updateSelectInput`: https://shiny.oxshef.io/tutorials_controls-dependent-on-data.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).